# That law does not apply to

Tags: discussion, scope

I have not been as active on this site has I had planned when it was in Area 51 forgive me if this has been addressed already. The closest thing I find is [Are hypothetical application of the law questions on topic?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34)

I have a half baked idea, and I wonder if Law.SE is the place for it to be explored.

We have all seen people (often in cars) who think this law or that law does not apply to them.  They park in the yellow striped areas of handicapped parking, and loading zones.  They drive down the shoulder in heavy traffic. The kinds of things where it is easy to get a picture or video showing the behavior with identifying information like the license plate or image of the one to whom that law does not apply, demonstrating their immunity. It seems pointless to call the authorities as the will be gone before the authorities arrive.

My idea is that you snap a picture or video, post it, define the place and time and ask for assistance in where to report the incident.  Presumably there will difficulties in finding the correct avenue to report and this proposal will help address them.  Somethings will very drastically by locality and event, as time progresses a data base of solutions (*or lack of*) will emerge.

Comment: How would a picture change the answer to "how do I report parking violations?"

Answer (score 1):

On the one hand, I have to agree that a picture won't change the answer to "how do I report parking violations?"

I'm also somewhat confused by your motivation in taking photos of these people and posting it online. Why? Are you trying to publicly shame them? This isn't the site for that.

We will also take steps to remove any personally identifiable information that you post, especially that of other people, so ensure that your question is valid without such information.

I also don't want a million of these questions, so what will happen is *if* you choose to do this, you may get one of each question answered, and all future questions will be closed as duplicates.

Comment: Agreed: The OP could be an interesting idea in crowd-sourcing crime control, but Stack Exchange is definitely not the place to try it out!